# Style "bottom:0" also aligns to left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, centering

I've set `bottom:0` to a div to align it at the bottom. But, even if my text is `text-center` it is align to the left. I would like to know why?

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 7%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Title" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="caption" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;">
          <p class="text-center">Title</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent div should have a width set to 100% of the page width  then the child p element will align itself to center of the page.

In your current snippet there is no width of the div element set thats is why its taking the width of its child element content.

Still it will be a little off from center due to the padding applied using the class content.

You should apply this padding only for the image container div.

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.padding7 {
  padding: 7%;
}
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="padding7">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Title" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
          <p class="text-center">Title</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For an absolutely *positioned* element, `text-center` won't work *on* the element as `absolute` elements are *taken out of the flow*.

You can center it using `transform` like this:

```
transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 7%;
}
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Title" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
          <p class="text-center">Title</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @homer let us know your thoughts on the answers here please?

Comment: Your answer is complete but a bit more complicated than @Deep one. Thank you